# Override or change the provider name of connection string in a dll for TLS 1.2 upgrade

Tags: c++, asp-classic, tls1.2

We disabled TLS 1.0  and 1.1 as a part of TLS 1.2 upgrade. We have changed the "Provider" in the sql connection strings in our classic asp application to `Provider=MSOLEDBSQL`. While testing the application, we were still facing issues related to the connection string. We did a little digging and found that our classic asp app is calling a dll (programmed in c++) which is registered in the registry. We do have the solution that built this dll, but it has too many syntax and reference missing errors and could be incomplete (since it is very old). The connection strings in this dll is still using `Provider=SQLOLEDB`

Below is one of the connections:
    `wsprintfW(wszConnectionStr,L"Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=%s;Database=%s;Uid=%s;Pwd=%s;UseProcForPrepare=0;OLE DB Services=0",(WCHAR*)bstrDBServerName, (WCHAR*)bstrDatabaseName, (WCHAR*)bstrUserAccount, (WCHAR*)bstrPassword);`

Since re-building the dll after making the provider name changes in the connection string is out of the picture due to the huge number of errors, is there any way to override just the connection string that the dll is using? Or is there any other way we can get over this issue?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: "Since re-building the dll after making the provider name changes in the connection string is out of the picture due to the huge number of errors" - Sounds to me like taking the few days it would require to get that component to build with the change and a modern compiler is the way to go. Along the way you may even fix a bug or two. That's what I would do. You don't want to be stuck in a situation where you can't or won't change some code for legacy or other reasons. Modernize your code now!

Comment: I'd need to see more of your code to know whether I can answer that question, but the use of connection strings in classic asp (which don't need to be compiled into dlls) is common.  My preferred method is to set one as an application variable in global.asa and then call it as `Application("conn") ` wherever necessary

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue and was able to fix it by just installing the latest SQL Native CLient from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50402
and add this as a provider for SQL DB Connectivity in Connection string "Provider=SQLNCLI11; DataTypeCompatibility=80; " This will fix the issue of TLS 1.2 by forcing the connection to use TLS1.2.